ASP.NET Core 6 app deployed on IIS gets 500 error "No route matches the supplied values"
Edit: Solved, turned out to be a routing problem in Program.cs
First I want to be clear that the app runs successfully when I run it through IIS Express on https://localhost. However, I am having trouble deploying it to IIS.
I published it to be framework-dependent, did all the requisite steps w/ IIS and installed the .net hosting bundle, etc. Despite having checked over my deployment setup many times, I still believe it is a problem w/ the way something is configured (rather than the code).
This is because my coworker managed to deploy the same app to IIS with no problems. He even sent over his publish folder for me to point my IIS site to, and I still got an error.
No breakpoints get hit in the code, even in Program.cs, and when I try to go anywhere other than the landing page I get a blank page w/ a 404 error in the console. Upon checking Event Viewer, the only error that is displayed is the same as when I go to the site ("No route matches the supplied values"). Same goes for when I enable logs in the publish folder.
Please let me know if you need more information. For reference, here is the full error I encounter on the site page:

InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.RedirectToActionResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, RedirectToActionResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync<TFilter, TFilterAsync>()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters.PreBufferRequestStreamMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.RegisterAdapterFeaturesMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.RegisterAdapterFeaturesMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)


Please try to install the IIS Rewrite Module(https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), you can open the site and scroll down, then we can find the download links.

If the rewrite module still not works, then we have to check the FREB Logs(https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/reading-a-freb-log-a-failed-request-tracing-iis-request/ba-p/1349639). If you don't know how to check it,  you can update it in the origin post. (Please hide your sensitive information)

Turned out to be a routing problem, somewhat predictably given the nature of the error code lol. However, you introduced me to a cool new tool (FREB logs), so thank you!
